# Find all possible quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Let H be a subgroup of a group G of prime order |H|=p.  Describe up to isomorphism all possible quotient groups F/N where N is a normal subgroup of G and N $\subset$ F $\subset$ $\langle H, N \rangle$.

I know that $H/(H \cap N) \cong HN/N$ and $H \cong$ $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but I don't know how to use this to get the desired result.

Comment: $H \cap N$ is normal in H and H is simple, right?

Comment: @Melihİşeri we're not given H is simple.  Where did you get that from?

Comment: $|H|=p$, and hence beyond being simple it has no subgroup other than (e) and H itself.

Comment: @Melihİşeri makes sense.  Could you please elaborate further where I'm supposed to go with this or what theorems I should be looking at?

Comment: $<H,N> = HN$ since N is normal. Therefore, you are looking for all possible subgroups of $HN/N$. You know what it is isomorphic to and you can say something about $(H\cap N)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgroup $\langle H, N \rangle$ generated by $H$ and $N$ is equal to $HN$ since $N$ is normal. So by the second isomorphism theorem, we have $HN/N \cong H / (H \cap N)$. Now, the subgroups between $HN$ and $N$ is the same as the subgroups of $HN/N$, which by the isomorphism is the subgroups of $H / (H \cap N)$. $H$ is cyclic of order $p$, and so $H / (H \cap N)$ either has two subgroups if $H \cap N = \{e\}$ and one subgroup if $H \cap N = H$.